# Kotlin Flow only collect every second

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have a Flow which downloads a file. The flow emits the download progress. I want to show the progress in the phone notification center, but only update the value once every second to prevent lagging the device.

My Flow:

```
return callbackFlow {
  someJavaCallback { progress ->
    trySend(progress)
  }

  close()
}
```

My CoroutineWorker, which displays the notification and downloads the file:

```
myFlow.collect { // update notification }
Result.Success()
```

My question is, how can I "throttle" the collection so that I for example collect 1%, but 1 second later it collects 5% and ignores all values between those two points

Answer (score 5):

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.throttleLatest(delayMillis: Long): Flow<T> = this
  .conflate()
  .transform {
    emit(it)
    delay(delayMillis)
  }
```

source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1446#issuecomment-1198103541

Comment: For simplicity, you could replace `transform` with `onEach` so you don't need to re-emit values.

Comment: @Tenfour04, if he uses onEach, the flow emits the first value after it waits the delay. In the example with transform it emits the first value before the delay, i.e. immediately.

Comment: @LGFox, excellent point.